# Can I View SMS online

Tags: sync, sms, onedrive

Since Windows Phone syncs photos, videos, apps settings and SMS to the cloud (OneDrive), Did Microsoft provides any URL to read the synced SMSs online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, there is no way to view your Text Messages (SMS) online.

[Windows Phone 8 does backup your text messages](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/back-up-my-stuff) (SMS and MMS), if the feature is enabled, but the backup is now viewable - it's safely stored somewhere in the cloud.

If you transfer to a new WP8 device, that information can be restored to the new handset.

Answer (score 3):

Backed up SMSes are displayed in Outlook.com categories, so:

1. Go to http://outlook.com
2. Click the cog -> Options -> Manage categories
3. Tick/check "Show in folder pane" and "Filter" for "Unread" and "Contacts", for example.
4. Go back to your inbox and click on the categories mentioned above to see relevant SMSes.

Comment: Wish I could vote this up 10 more times. It works! This needs to be spread far and wide... Now, any idea how to sync that down to a PC? I managed to add the account to Outlook 2013 as an ActiveSync account, but that doesn't seem to offer the "Categories" thing. I don't know how to add it as an Exchange account (if even possible) because its email address is on a personal domain, not an @outlook.com or whatever.

Comment: Have you tried moving them to another folder? If that works you might be able to set up a rule to move incoming texts to automate the process.

Comment: I can't tell what folder they're in to start with - I guess it's hidden - but I took a message I won't miss if it gets removed from my backup and moved it to the inbox. It shows up there on the web, but not on Outlook (even after synching).