# On Windows Phone, where can you view your backed up text messages

Tags: backup

On Windows phone you can back up your text messages by going to Settings > Applications > Messaging > Text message backup (flick on)

My question is:

How can I view these text messages online? Is there a place on SkyDrive (OneDrive) where I can view these messages?

Also I if get a new phone (or factory reset my phone) where to I restore from backup?

Comment: See [my answer](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/11561/2143) to [the linked question](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/can-i-view-sms-online/11561).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How can I view text messages online? Is there a place on SkyDrive (OneDrive) where I can view these messages?**

There is currently no way to view text messages online.

**How do I restore from backup if I get a new phone or factory reset my phone ?**

> 1. When you first set up your phone, sign in using the same Microsoft
>      account you used when you created your backup.
> 2. When prompted to restore your phone, tap the backup you want to use, tap Next, and then tap Next again.

You can find the complete instructions here : [Windowsphone.com -- How-to restore a backup to my phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/restore-a-backup-to-my-phone)