# How can I retrieve a deleted conversation in my text messages on Nokia Lumia 635?

Tags: sms, backup

I had a whole important conversation in my text messages and I accidentally deleted it. I haven't backed-up my phone in two weeks, so I'm wondering if there's a chance to get back that conversation with the messages from that person? It's important. Thank you.

Comment: Did you have Messaging backup on? (Somewhat separate from "backing up your phone".) If not, then your carrier would be the one to check with.

Comment: Drop a note to NSA.GOV and see if they'd send you a copy... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Annoyingly, the only reliable way that anybody seems to know of to access phone backups is to activate your Microsoft Account on a phone for the first time. You can use a second phone for this, or just hard-reset your current phone. If you were backing up text messages - and haven't made a new backup since you deleted the important conversation - you should be able to restore the conversation that way.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer that I just discovered: **it is possible, via Outlook.com, to view SMS messages you've backed up**. Taken from [this answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/11561/15445), which should have a lot more upvotes:

1. Go to https://outlook.com/. Log in with the Microsoft Account used on your phone.
2. Click the Gear icon in the upper right, next to your photo. Select `Manage Categories` (or `Options`, then `Manage Categories` on the next screen).
3. Check the boxes under "Show in folder pane" for *Contacts* and *Photos*. You can check the others too, if you want.
4. Go back to your inbox, and you'll see a list of "Categories" on the left-side panel.

Under `Contacts`, you will see your backed-up SMS, but so far as I can tell only the ones that you've received appear there (and only if you use "Arrange by *Conversation*").

Under `Photos`, you will see your backed up MMS (at least, the ones containing images), both sent and received.

Hope that's enough to help you out!